# For which values of k this expression holds true : $\sum{n=1^\infty} k^n(A^n+kA^{n+1) = kA $

Tags: matrices

A= $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    3 & 0 & 0 \\
    2 & 7 & 0 \\
    4 & 8 & 1\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

For which values of k this expression holds true :

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty k^n(A^n+kA^{n+1}) = kA $$

What I did

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty k^n(A^n+kA^{n+1}) = kA - k^{N+1}A^{N+1}$$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$ using method of differences

$-1<k<1$

But the answer is

$-1/7<k<1/7$

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagonal entries of $A^n$ are $1, 7^n$ and $3^n$.  $k$ must be small enough to send each of those towards zero.

Comment: Can you give a little more explanation

Comment: What would be the diagonal entries of $k^nA^n$ ?

Comment: And if k is less than 1 and greater than -1 then it will automatically go to zero

Comment: Bit the central entry is $k^n7^n=(7k)^n$, so that won^t always go to zero.